# javascript optimisation and minification vs. gzipping

Tags: javascript, optimization, compression, gzip

I noticed that minifier do not perform that good with prototypical javascript since they do not replace any method or properties if they start with this. For example:

```
// unoptimized 182 bytes
myClass.prototype.myFunction = function(){
    this.myElementDom.style.backgroundColor='#000';
    this.myElementDom.style.color='#FFF';
    this.myElementDom.style.borderColor='#DDD';
}

// 168 bytes = 92% of unoptimized, YUI compressed
myClass.prototype.myFunction=function(){this.myElementDom.style.backgroundColor="#000";this.myElementDom.style.color="#FFF";this.myElementDom.style.borderColor="#DDD"};

// optimized 214 bytes
// set a replaceable local scope variable and reduce 2 variable 
// lookups at the same time
// file-size in the development version doesn't matter, so we can even increase it 
// to preserve readability
myClass.prototype.myFunction = function(){
    var myElementDomStyle = this.myElementDom.style
    myElementDomStyle.backgroundColor='#000';
    myElementDomStyle.color='#FFF';
    myElementDomStyle.borderColor='#DDD';
}

// 132 bytes = 72.53% of unoptimized, YUI compressed
myClass.prototype.myFunction=function(){var a=this.myElementDom.style;a.backgroundColor="#000";a.color="#FFF";a.borderColor="#DDD"};
```

Hurray, 19.47% saved... NOT ...when publishing the script with gzip enabled, the unoptimized, YUI compressed version loads with 130 bytes (=71.42% from unoptimized) and obviously gains more savings than the optimized, YUI compressed version with 134 bytes (=73.63% from unoptimized)... might be obvious after thinking about how compression works, but wich way to go now? Do this micro optimisation and smaller compression in the first place justify a bigger file-size with gzip... Since you easily can make your code less readable and maintainable with such optimisations.

all informations according to http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: You may use google closure minifier. Also `gzip` + `minify` is still better than only `gzip`.

Comment: Isn't the second example more about reducing DOM lookups at runtime rather than looking for space savings?

Answer (score 1):

Code readability shouldn't come into it - you should only be minifying on the production server and developing on un-minified code. Don't micro optimize your variable and function names, you will almost certainly be sacrificing code readability for an almost zero gain in usability - you're talking about a few KB of a file which is going to be downloaded once and cached.

As for whether to minify and gzip or just gzip - do whichever produces the smaller overall filesize.

Answer (score 1):

In any event 182 bytes of code isn't going to minify or compress much. Minification works by eliminating whitespace—which you only have 16 bytes of in your five lines of code—and shortening function, variable and property names, which it can't do in this case for reasons of scope. Compression works by finding repeated sequences and eliminating them. There's simply not enough text in your five lines of code for much repetition to be found.

Try minifying and compressing 50 or 100 or more lines of code and you'll see more compelling results. And, as @rgvcorley suggests, you should focus on making your code readable and maintainable in your development environment and leave the smaller details of file size up to your build process and web server.

Answer (score 1):

One thing does not exclude another: you can do both minimization and gzipping JS files (gzipping occurs at webserver level typically). I think it will provide best results.
Minimization and compression works better on larger files.

In addition to making JS smaller I would look at:

1. Merging JS file into one minified file to reduce number of HTTP requests
2. Optimizing HTTP caching settings
3. Putting JS into CDN to reduce download time
4. Using public CDNs for some common JS libraries e.g. jQuery, so it is more likely to be taken from user's local cache
5. Adding JS files and the end of HTML page

Check your website with http://www.webpagetest.org/ to get report what other things could be improved

For more information I would recommend Reading [High Performance Web Sites](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529307.do) book. It covers nany scenarios how some even simple changes can dramatically improve page loading time

Comment: I think my question wasn't worded that clear, I did not plan to publish my code unminified. I'm currently reading the book you've pointed out, which's the reason I tried to reduce variable lookups and optimize minification :-)